# WPF - SuggestAppend for Textbox

Tags: wpf

I am looking for a textbox control that suggests words as the user types, similar to SuggestAppend for textboxes in winforms, except for WPF. I have looked around on the WPFToolkit and haven't really found anything that fits my needs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Declare an enum AutoCompleteMode too with value(Append, None,SuggestAppend,Suggest)

```
public enum AutoCompleteMode
```

Create an custom UserControl with TextBox and ItemControls. Handle the **KeyDown** event of TextBox. Popup an custom List to show the suggestion list(ItemControls in here). Then Handle the selection of the ItemControls. Can custom the style of hte ItemControls's ItemTemplate. Apply the AutoCOmpleteMode in this UserControl and handle the Enum changed in the code behind.

Comment: Completely new to making my own controls, would you use the listbox or some other control for the itemcontrols?

Comment: ItemsControl: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

WpfToolkit contains [AutoCompleteBox](https://github.com/dotnetprojects/WpfToolkit/blob/master/WpfToolkit/Input/AutoCompleteBox/System/Windows/Controls/AutoCompleteBox.cs) that you can use for auto suggest feature.
You will have to define a collection for items to suggest (SuggestionItems) and set it as ItemsSource on AutoCompleteBox control.

```
<someNamespaceAlias:AutoCompleteBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding SuggestionItems}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Currently using this exact library, lol. It doesn't support suggestappend, what it does is that it gets the suggestion and totally replaces the previous text of that textbox with that suggestion. I want something that suggest words as the user types so the suggested words are being appended.

Comment: It also has a  **IsTextCompletionEnabled** property - Gets or sets a value indicating whether the first possible match found during the filtering process will be displayed automatically  in the text box . I am not sure if this is same as suggest append that you need.. Please let know in comments with an example if suggestappend is something different.

Comment: I have that set to false. It autosuggests for the first word in the textbox but not the following. What I'm looking for is something like:

let's say that the suggestion array is ["Hello", "World", "StackOverflow"].

In the textbox, if the user types in phrases that are contained in that suggestion array, those suggestions should be prompted. The phrase should reset for every space (I can be flexible here). 

So it should be like, the user types H, and Hello pops up and the user can select that and then the user types in W and World pops up, allowing the user to select that and so forth.